# Failed to use input() while using python in Visual Studio Code - Input() can't fetch any lines again

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I had a strange problem coding with python in Visual Studio Code.
Here is a simple test:

```
number = input('Please input a number: ')
while True:
    number = input('Please input a number: ')
    print(number)
```

In the VS Code Python terminal, after input once, the `input()` stop getting new inputs and start getting `null` from nowhere just like this:

```
Please input a number: 1
Please input a number:
Please input a number:
Please input a number:
Please input a number:
Please input a number:
Please input a number:
Please input a number:
Please input a number:
......
```

But when I run the same code in PyCharm or in command line, everything works just fine.

Pycharm:

```
Please input a number:1
Please input a number:2
Please input a number:3
......
```

Command Line:

```
>>> while True:
...     number = input('please input a number:')
...     print(number)
...
please input a number:1
1
please input a number:2
2
please input a number:3
3
please input a number:4
4
......
```

Please tell me if there is a solution.

More info:
VScode version: 1.25.0
Python extensions: 2018.7.1

Comment: which version of python are you using in VScode?

Comment: @NipunSampath 3.5.4

Comment: PyCharm doesn't look right. It's not printing the number

Comment: @PeterWood Oh my fault, the former test code on pycharm doesn't have the `print(number)`

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing **ctrl + shift + d** and select integrated terminal/console instead of python terminal.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work well, the problem still exist, this is my setting in launch.json
`{
            "name": "Integrated Terminal/Console",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit"
            ]
        },`

Comment: I read somewhere that the Debug Console does not support programs that need to read input from the console, maybe try the external terminal/console option

Comment: Not work so well, the problem still there, I wonder if it is a bug of vscode X(